# Show lines around cursor while typing in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to be able to see some lines around my cursor while typing as it is more comfortable. For comparison, this is done with the `scrolloffset` option in vim, which, when the cursor is moved toward the edge of the screen, starts scrolling `scrolloffset` lines before the end, leaving context above/below the cursor. Is there a similar option to this in Microsoft Word?

Comment: Could you elaborate with a picture of the behavior in vim?

Answer (score 0):

**no**, there is no similar option in Word